# Fragment lifecycle events while fragment transaction commit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, accessibility, race-condition

In the following extension function I'm adding a `OnBackStackChangedListener` to a fragment manager and then I'm setting the accessibility focus on the top fragment with a view and hiding the others:

```
private fun FragmentManager.setUpForAccessibility() {
        val listener = FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {
            if (fragments.isNotEmpty()) {
                val lastFragmentWithView = fragments.last {
                    it.view != null
                }

                for (fragment in fragments) {
                    if (fragment === lastFragmentWithView) {
                        fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility =
                            View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES
                    } else {
                        fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility =
                            View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS
                    }
                }
            }
        }.also {
            addOnBackStackChangedListener(it)    
        }
    }
```

This code has is almost exactly the solution I've read from [here](https://medium.com/@guygriv/accessibility-and-fragment-transactions-1aef5596f9d4)
From my knowledge the `fragment.view` will return a non-null value only if the fragment's layout is already inflated and I couldn't find the document explicitly mention the relation between calling `commit()` and the added fragment's layout's inflation, and because of that the `fragment.view?.importantForAccessibility = View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES` can set the focuse on a wrong view.

I have tried the following for finding out in what sequence `commit()`, `onCreateView()` and my `onBackStackChanged` were being executed:

- debugging: sequence: (`commit() -> onCreateView() -> onBackStackChanged()`)
- running the app and testing using Talkback (the accessibility issue was fixed and the focus was on the right fragment)
- I also checked the threads that these functions were running in and they were all on the same thread
- I tried to make sense of the source code for performing a `commit()` in `FragmentManagerImpl` it seems to me that reporting the back stack change happens after the `commit()` takes place and `moveState` function in `FragmentManagerImpl` seems to cause the fragment's view to be inflated. but since the codes where pretty difficult to understand I'm still worried about the **race conditions** that may occur so I came here to ask for help.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.